# Можете подсказать, правильно ли считает данная программа?

Tags: c++, математика, численные-методы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const double e = 2.7182;
    int n=0;

    while (true)
    {
        cout << "enter the number by which to divide the function definition scope: ";
        cin >> n;
        if (!cin) {
            cout << "this input is invalid.  Please try again.\n";
            cin.clear();
            while (cin.get() != '\n');
        }
        else break;
    }


    
    double y, k = 2.0 / n;
    
    double x = k;
    
    y = acos(pow(e, 0)) - 2 * sin(0);
    
    double b = 0, a = fabs(y);
    
    while (x <= 2) {
        y = acos(pow(e, x)) - 2 * sin(x);
        if (a >= abs(y)) {
            b = x;
            a = abs(y);
        }
        x += k;
    }
    cout << "root of the equation is: " << x;
    return 0;

}
```

вот условие данной задачи: Необходимо приближенно найти корень уравнения f(x) = 0 для
функции из своего варианта. Корень нужно найти по следующему алгоритму:
перебираем значения от начала до конца значение функции, минимальное по модулю. Аргумент, при котором оно
достигается, считаем корнем уравнения. Программа должна запросить у
пользователя, на сколько частей разделить область поиска корня, вычислить шаг,
с которым нужно проходить значения, пройти в цикле нужные значения, найти
корень и вывести его.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы бы для начала оформили вопрос так, чтоб задание было видно, а не было куском кода, как и рисунок... По сути — как минимум, очень странный алгоритм... Так вы даже решение уравнения `x^2+1=0` найдете — минимум-то есть... Вместо жуткого приближения e с 4 знаками и `pow(e, x)` можно написать нормальное `exp(x)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вы просто запустите, посчитайте — у вас выдает ответ 2. Но правильный корень - 2.31458. Значит, ваша программа неверная.

Если вы ее измените как

```
double y, k = 2.0 / n;

double x = 1;

y = acos(exp(-x)) - 2 * sin(x);

double b = x, a = fabs(y);

while (x <= 3) {
    y = acos(exp(-x)) - 2 * sin(x);
    if (a >= abs(y)) {
        b = x;
        a = abs(y);
    }
    x += k;
}
cout << "root of the equation is: " << b << endl;
```

то при очень больших `n` получите что-то похожее на правду.